# Restrict user from entering tab in a textfield using regular expression

Tags: tab, text

I want to restrict the user from entering a tab in a text field using regular expression.

Comment: Is this field in a Lightning component, Visualforce page, a standard Salesforce page layout, or somewhere else? I think you can accomplish this in any of those scenarios, but the approach will be very different.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ ]{2,}
```

It will check 2 or more spaces
You could also check that before and after those spaces words follow. (not other whitespace like tabs or new lines)

```
\w[ ]{2,}\w
```

The same, but you can also pick (capture) only the spaces for tasks like replacement

```
\w([ ]{2,})\w
```

or see that before and after spaces there is anything, not only word characters (except whitespace)

```
[^\s]([ ]{2,})[^\s]
```

To be specific about Tab, you can use. It will check 1 or more that once tab

```
[ \t]{1,}
```